# How could I display the last modified date of the product in the backend

Tags: magento2

I would like to display when a product was last modified on the backend of a item page. How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

As the `updated_at` field is already in the table: `catalog_product_entity` you can show it in backend product grid by using below code in your custom module.

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_listing.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="product_columns" class="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns">
        <column name="updated_at" component="Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date">
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Last Modified</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">80</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
    </columns>
</listing>
```

Comment: I actually found another solution and made a patch for it. You can aswell just change the is_visible for it to 1.

Comment: Okay good to hear that.